# Change the app background color by using a ToggleButton in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-togglebutton

I am working on an Android app and I want to change the **background color** of the app by using a **toggle button** (*"Dark" and "Light" Themes*).

This is the code I tried so far, but it does not change the color, despite not giving any errors.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private RelativeLayout backgroundEl;
private ToggleButton toggle;

protected void onCreate(RelativeLayout RelativeLayout) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.onCreate(backgroundEl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container));
}

protected void onCreate(ToggleButton toggleButton) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.onCreate(toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1));
    toggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (toggle.isChecked())     
                backgroundEl.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            else
                backgroundEl.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }   
    });
}
```

}

And this is the **activity_main.xml** file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.avatar_test.MainActivity" >

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/gallery1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:text="ToggleButton" />
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why** do you have **2** `onCreate()` methods?
And **why** their signature is **weird**, meaning different from `public final void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)`?

Please correct (and make just **1** out of the **2** you had before) your `onCreate()` method like so:

```
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    backgroundEl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

    toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    toggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (toggle.isChecked())     
                backgroundEl.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            else
                backgroundEl.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }   
    });
}
```

Comment: Watch out people might consider you rude by you telling how to proper override a method !

Comment: @forcewill Why should a help be considered `rude`? I simply gave a working solution. Ah, I see. your answer was considered `rude` and it was closed after a shower of downvotes, unfortunately. I didn't consider it so, but sometimes people here are too much `sensible`.

Comment: Your answer is perfect :P Im just being ironic about my previous answer that was deleted and i was called rude by providing the proper signature for the.
Im fact i just up vote it :p

Comment: @forcewill Thank you, dear, I'm sorry that you weren't understood.